# Android: Logcat doesn't show anything in Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, logcat

Logcat output is emtpy in Intellij IDEA - what to do?
An application is running (live wallpaper), log level is Verbose, device is chosen correctly, ADB and USB debugging are enabled.

Comment: IDEA version? Android platform version? Does command line `adb logcat` show the log?

Comment: IDEA Ultimate 11.1, Android 4.0.3 and... sorry, where to write 'adb logcat'? I can't find adb program in SDK's directory and cannot find something like console in IDEA.

Comment: `android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe`. Also try IDEA 11.1.4: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11.1+EAP.

Comment: Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory
I tried this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=17774398&postcount=93 and it didn't help.

Comment: It appears to be ROM/device specific issue. Flashing new or alternative ROM may help.

Comment: I forgot to reboot the device. Thank you - works now.

Answer (score 12):

Pressing the following button always fixes it for me.

[image]

Comment: of course, but also wipes your filter config -.- Sadly I don't know a better solution - only the device monitor will work as expected and there we can't jump to code :-/

Answer (score 5):

I often see this problem with eclipse IDE, restart IDE (or ADB by command line) is my solution.

to restart ADB:

sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server

Answer (score 4):

It seems that adb sometimes gets disconnected from Intellij.  You could restart the server or Intellij, but it's easier to just go to:

Tools -> Android

and then turn "Enable ADB Integration" off and then back on.

Comment: (I only added this solution because it's fairly easy and the "Only Show Logcat..." solution wasn't working for me).

Answer (score 3):

[image: Intructions]

Just restart your logging in IntelliJ. My version is 15.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem as well. 
But temporary solution is from menu go to "tools>Android>Monitor (DDMS included)"
It will be displayed Android Debug Monitor and you will be able to see your logs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Eclipse/ADT is not running in parallel and accessing the phone.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a direct answer to your question but a possible solution if you're willing to migrate:

I kept on having this problem, sometimes a restart worked temporarily. After a while I decided to give Android Studio's a try (which is build upon Intellij). I haven't had the problem for a while and Android Studio's feels a lot like Intellij, love it!

Answer (score 0):

In my situation "Resume" (see: **Run -> Resume** in AndroidStudio) was colored. After clicking the lable Locgat did it's job...

I really don't know what messed up my phone (running Lollipop) the last hour - but I never had such a fight to get adb / logcat running.

It seems that the system had stored the state of the application through a reboot oO Is this possible, at all? I don't know why AndroidStudio showed the resume-entry "highlighted", after the rebooting my device I didn't run the app...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Instructions]

If you are newbie to android like me, I was pulling my hairs out for not being able to debug. It so just happened to be that i 'accidentally' pressed that little button which hides this screen. Click it again and it will come back.

I hope this answer will be useful for you, and for many others.